# convert string having time to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var timeString=$('.csstdhighlight').closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();

//getting timestrinfg like this
timeString="07:15 PM07:30 PM07:45 PM08:00 PM08:15 PM08:30 PM08:45 PM";
```

I have to convert string to array.
So that I can get *Start time* and *end time* from `array arra[0]` will get Start time, `array[array.length-1]` will get end time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression would do the job; for just the start and stop times:

```
var re = /^(\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M).*(\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)$/,
match = timeString.match(re);

console.log(match[1]); // "07:15 PM"
console.log(match[2]); // "08:45 PM"
```

Alternatively, match all time patterns:

```
var re = /\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M/g;
console.log(timeString.match(re));
// ["07:15 PM", "07:30 PM", "07:45 PM", "08:00 PM", "08:15 PM", "08:30 PM", "08:45 PM"]
```

**Update**

Seeing how the regular expression for each time has a constant length and you only want the first and last, you can even do this:

```
timeString.substr(0, 8); // "07:15 PM"
timeString.substr(-8);   // "08:45 PM"
```

Comment: Jack match variable is what

Comment: @Means It's the result of matching the expression against the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` method.

```
var n = timeString.split(" ");
start = n[0];
end = n[n.length - 1];
```

Comment: I think Jack's answer using regex's might be more appropriate.